# Unable to run full test suite on Android devices using webdriverio (individual tests are fine)

Tags: android, appium, webdriver-io, appium-android

I'm trying to run my WebdriverIO tests against an Android phone, connected locally. Running the tests individually with the `--spec /folder_with_tests/test.js` command works fine every time. However, if I don't use `--spec` and try to run the whole suite, I can't connect to my phone properly.

Maybe 1 in 15 tests will randomly pass. The rest produce errors like the ones below:

`ERROR: ESOCKETTIMEDOUT`

`ERROR: A session is either terminated or not started`

`ERROR: An unknown server-side error occurred while processing the command. Original error: Cannot read property 'shutdown' of null`

Also, odd things happen like the camera turning on and off. I've tried different phones and the same thing happens every time.

Has anyone else had this issue? Or know of a solution?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As it turns out, one of the developers on my team (who has since left) pushed some strange files in the root of the project:

`failed`
`fibers@2.0.0`
`mocha_webdriverio_poc@0.0.1`
`node`
`wdio`

All were blank and didn't affect anything other than Android tests and, even then, only when run all together. Not sure whether these have been autogenerated, but he probably just used `git add -A`, then committed & pushed everything.

I deleted all the files and everything worked as normal.

Answer (score 0):

Check the official article about [organising suite in wdio](http://webdriver.io/guide/testrunner/organizesuite.html) :

To group test you need:

```
// wdio.conf.js
exports.config = {
    // define all tests
    specs: ['./test/specs/**/*.spec.js'],
    // ...
    // define specific suites
    suites: {
        login: [
            './test/specs/login.success.spec.js',
            './test/specs/login.failure.spec.js'
        ],
        otherFeature: [
        // ...
        ]
    },
    // ...
}
```

and then you can run suite:

```
$ wdio wdio.conf.js --suite login
```

Comment: I might give that a try, but I just want to be able to run `wdio wdio.conf.js` without having to organise into suites, which works for every other browser. It used to work on Android phones before Christmas, too. I'm not sure what's gone wrong!